# how could monitor device status using raspberry pi

Tags: raspberry-pi, scada, scada-ignition

I want to build a small project which will monitor some devices(pump,ac etc) status(on/off, current/voltage level etc). I have decided to use raspberry pi 3 as a server. I am thinking about scada. is it efficient to do these works? also i am not familiar to scada. is there anyone to guide me--

```
 where should i start? 
 what is the suitable software for doing it??
```

Comment: Do not understand why you were down voted.

Answer (score 1):

You could just use Python and the RPi.GPIO module to control and monitor the GPIO pins on the Raspberry. Python is powerful, open-script and easy to get into.

You would need to develop a bread-board to protect your Raspberry and allow for monitoring higher voltages.

Some example code on using GPIO with Sockets here: https://github.com/matzpersson/raspberry-gpio-sockets

Answer (score 1):

You may use ScadaLTS on Raspberry.
In ScadaLTS have available modbus protocol among many others.
This is web oriented software with graphics views drag and drop editor.

For now you may read GPIO data programmatically to file and use ASCII File Reader DataSource. 
We plan to have datasource dedicated for GPIO.

ScadaLTS based on ScadaBR - fast tutorial https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JjOQWwoaQuQ.

Answer (score 1):

you could also check out mySCADA. they make a solution for Raspberry pi at http://www.smarthouse.cloud
you can use the GPIO on the Pi or talk to industrial PLC's.